# How can this CNN for the portfolio management problem be implemented in keras?

Tags: keras, cnn, reinforcement-learning

In the paper "[A Deep Reinforcement Learning Framework for the Financial Portfolio Management Problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.10059.pdf)" the CNN in the picture below is applied on the portfolio management problem.

[image: CNN]

I am trying to understand how this network works and can be implemented in keras.

What I don't understand is, why do we have 20+1 feature maps after the second convolution? And how I am supposed to include the portfolio w from last period in keras?

My current implementation is as follows:

```
def network(self):
    input1 = Input(shape=(3, 50, 4))
    conv1 = Conv2D(2, (1, 3), activation='relu',)(input1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(10, (1, 48), activation='relu')(conv1)
    conv3 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='relu')(conv2)
    flat1 = Flatten()(conv3)
    preds = Activation('softmax')(flat1)
    model = Model(input1, preds)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse') # todo loss function
    return model
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your tensors in Keras. I have written the model below

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense, LSTM, Input, concatenate, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad

price_history = Input(shape=(11, 50, 3))
feature_maps = Conv2D(2, (1, 3), activation='relu')(price_history)
feature_maps = Conv2D(20, (1, 48), activation='relu')(feature_maps)

# Add the w from the last period
w_last = Input(shape=(11, 1, 1))
feature_maps = concatenate([feature_maps, w_last], axis = -1)
feature_map = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='relu')(feature_maps)
feature_map = Flatten()(feature_map)

# Add the cash bias
cash_bias = Input(shape=(1,))
feature_map = concatenate([feature_map, cash_bias], axis = -1)
w = Activation('softmax')(feature_map)

model = Model(inputs=[price_history, w_last, cash_bias], outputs=w)
print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am not sure about the loss function, I have not read the paper in detail. But this model describes what they have in the paper.